# xslt namespace prefix not getting removed

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I have checked multiple posts here added exclude-result-prefixes, also tried specifiyinh

```
<xsl:template match="pc:*" priority="-0.2">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

all these methods i have given try but the namespace prefix is still not getting removed.

Can somebody please help me how to remove namespace and just have it on top

ex:

```
Input xml

    <Workstart>
       <Work/>
    </Workstart>

XSLT

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="pc">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Work">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <pc:test1/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required output xml

```
    <Workstart xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" >
      <Work>
       <pc:test1/>
      </Work>
    </Workstart>
```

Comment: Why doesn't your required output have the namespace declaration for the prefix `pc`? It is an invalid XML. `<Work>
    <test1/>
    </Work>` makes sense though

Comment: Its just conversion from one xml to another

Comment: And your output is not a valid XML!! An XML cannot contain undeclared prefixes.. Your output has `pc` prefix, which isn't associated to any namespace.

Comment: Your "test1" node belongs to a particular namespace that is denoted by the prefix you have provided. You cannot strip away the namespace of a node and still say that a particular node belongs to a particular namespace via a prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In response to your edited question:***

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Workstart">
    <Workstart>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </Workstart>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Work">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        <pc:test1/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your new **input** example:

```
<Workstart>
    <Work/>
</Workstart>
```

will return the following **result***:

```
<Workstart xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
   <Work>
      <pc:test1/>
   </Work>
</Workstart>
```

--
(*) As I mentioned before, the *exact* result may depend on your specific processor.

Comment: Hey my major question was that i want to remove name space prefix. If i remove namespace as you said it doesnt give me pc:tes1 , only gives test1. Thats not what i expected.

Comment: As I said, you cannot have a prefix without a namespace.You *can* have a namespace without a prefix (see the end of my post), but not the other way round.

Comment: I agree with what you say but i want that prefix to go to top of declaration and while here i dont want to see it

Comment: would that be possible to declare at top as shown above

Comment: This doesnt change the declaration to top when i tried.. is there any other way to change it . please see the edit

Comment: I have tested this with three different processors (libxslt, Xalan and Saxon) and it works on all three of them. But as I said, an XSLT processor is free to put the namespace declaration anywhere it likes (as long as the meaning is preserved), so it may not **look** exactly the same with your specific processor. You should not be concerned about this, because the **meaning** is the same.

Comment: I think i am particularly concerned because i have multiple PC prefixes in my document so i cant have it at each place if i can have it looking as at single place , i am not sure if this makes much difference

Comment: @UshaswarnaKiranmayi There is only so much time I can devote to this. If your case is different than what you posted, then edit your question and post a **representative** example (and stop trying to edit my answer).

Comment: :Sorry to misinterpret and take our time. i am new to stackoverflow, so i am just learning interfaces,I have edited the question, please let me know if that would be possible to change